# NoneType Error in python

Tags: python, testing

I run this code but i got the typeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
what is problem ??

```
import bibtex
import unittest

class TestAuthorExtract(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
       self.simple_author_1 = "Smith"

   def test_author_1(self):
       # Test only surname
       (Surname , FirstNames) = bibtex.extract_author(self.simple_author_1)
       self.assertEqual((Surname , FirstNames) , ("Smith", ""))

if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here is the error message:

```
====================================================================== 
ERROR: test_author_1 (main.TestAuthorExtract)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "div.py", line 10, in test_author_1 
    (Surname , FirstNames) = bibtex.extract_author(self.simple_author_1) 
  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Ran 1 test in 0.001s FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: It is in this line       (Surname , FirstNames) = bibtex.extract_author(self.simple_author_1)

Comment: ======================================================================
ERROR: test_author_1 (__main__.TestAuthorExtract)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "div.py", line 10, in test_author_1
    (Surname , FirstNames) = bibtex.extract_author(self.simple_author_1)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)

Answer (score 2):

This means, that `bibtex.extract_author()` returns `None`. After that, the interpreter tried to assign the value to the tuple `(Surname, Firstname)`, which can be done only with iterables of the length 2 (that's called [unpacking](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples#Packing_and_Unpacking)).